# Which countries are allies of Israel? Which countries are enemies of Israel?

Tags: international-relations, israel

Which countries are allies of Israel? Which countries are enemies of Israel? Which countries recognize Israel and which countries do not recognise Israel?

Comment: I approved an edit which removed the "Zionist / Anti-Zionist" part of the question, because it's a [dog whistle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog-whistle_politics) and it's redundant when you are already asking for allies and enemies of Israel. But I am still not sure if this is a good question. There are about 200 countries in the world, and in most cases their relationship with Israel can be complicated.

Comment: I've VTC'd as too broad. But as a comment, I'd note that it's theoretically possible for a country to not recognise Israel but secretly be allied to it - it's been alleged about Saudi Arabia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93Saudi_Arabia_relations

Answer (score 4):

According to [a resolution of Congress urging Iraq to recognise Israel](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BILLS-110hres1249ih/pdf/BILLS-110hres1249ih.pdf):

> the following countries still do not recognize Israel’s
>   right to exist: Afghanistan, Algeria, Bahrain, Bangladesh,
>   Bhutan, Brunei, Chad, Comoros, Cuba, Djibouti, Guinea, Indonesia, Iran, Iraq, Kuwait, Lebanon, Libya,
>   Malaysia, <strike>Maldives</strike>, Mali, Morocco, Niger, North Korea,
>   Oman, Pakistan, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Somalia, Sudan,
>   Syria, Tunisia, United Arab Emirates, and Yemen;

(The Maldives has since established diplomatic relations with Israel. South Sudan also now has diplomatic relations with Israel.)

All other countries recognise Israel.  Among countries that recognize Israel are some with that are generally supportive, such as the USA, and others that generally oppose Israel, such as Egypt (which formally recognises Israel  as a result of the 1979 peace treaty.)

Many countries have a complex relationship with Israel, supporting its right to exist, and having a positive trading relationship, while being openly critical of some of Israel's policies towards its neighbours.

Various countries have some sort of defence arrangement with Israel, to allow for arms sales etc, but no country has a formal treaty of mutual defence similar to NATO.

Comment: As this is an "Israel" question. I'll remind commenters that if they wish to debate the general topic of Palestine, please use the [chat] instead of the comment thread.